# Who introduced the "dagger"symbol as conjugate transpose in quantum mechanics?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, linear-algebra

The $\dagger$ symbol is often used in quantum mechanics,and also often in general mathematics to represent the conjugate transpose operation.For Hermitian matrices we can write $$A^\dagger=A$$Who introduced this notation?

Comment: Who introduced this in QM literature, or generally in the mathematical literature?

Comment: Actually interested to know about both!

Comment: I would have thought that Dirac's 1939 paper "A new notation for quantum mechanics" was the answer, but I was wrong.  In fact, a cursory search of my library's bookshelves shows no QM books by big-name authors using this notation (Pauli, Dirac, v Neumann, Landau and Lifshitz).  I'm sure there's examples, but it would be nice to have a particular instance.

Comment: Someone who shouldn't have (editorializing here) since it's difficult to tell from a plain old "t" to those of us with aging eyesight.

Comment: @ConsigliereZARF Very good!

Answer (score 10):

In a now-deleted comment,  Consigliere ZARF listed a number of papers published in *Zeitschrift für Physik* in the late 1920's that used this notation.  The earliest was Pascual Jordan's 1927 ["Über eine neue Begründung der Quantenmechanik"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01390903), using the notation on pp.816-817; with about 10 other papers published in the following few years, all in the *ZfP*, all behind a paywall.
According to Duncan and Janssen ["(Never) Mind your p’s and q’s:
Von Neumann versus Jordan on the
Foundations of Quantum Theory"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.6511.pdf), p.57, the Jordan paper was where the notation was introduced.  The [paper](https://eudml.org/doc/159201) "Über die Grundlagen der Quantenmechanik" by 
D. Hilbert, J. von Neumann, and L. Nordheim, *Mathematische Annalen* (1928) uses (on page 19) $A^+$ for the adjoint of $A$.

Up to the point reading Consigliere ZARF's comment I had focused on English-language literature, which seemed to lag about a decade behind the German.  The rest of this post describes what I found there.

An approximate answer: Google books search for "dagger+Hermitian"  led to these early uses of the notation.

Page 59 of W. H. [Furry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendell_H._Furry)'s 1938 ["Note on the Theory of the Neutral Particle"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6c7f/0814480b494cc30ac24e421441ecfd96f270.pdf),
Phys. Rev. vol 54, p.56  has this:

> In dealing with such matrices we shall use
>   an asterisk (*) to indicate the complex conjugate
>   matrix, a prime (') to indicate the transposed
>   matrix, and a dagger ($\dagger$) to indicate the Hermitian adjoint matrix.

which seems to me to be an indication that this notation needed explaining.  A few years later, Booth and Wilson, in ["Radiative processes involving fast mesons"](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1940.0071) (*Proc. Roy Soc A*, v175, July 1940) wrote this in a footnote on p.487:

> Note that in order to
>   conform to the usual custom we modify Kemmer’s notation and use a dagger to denote
>   the Hermitian conjugate.

indicating that the notation had by then become standard (although not universal, or else Kemmer's notation from the year before would not have needed adjusting).

For all I know, it is possible that Furry was the true original introducer of the dagger notation.  It is certain that the notation was in use in the late 1930's.

Added: Furry cites an earlier paper of his (Phys Rev v51, p.125 (1937) and [another](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHP_1936__6_2_109_0.pdf) by Pauli ("Contributions mathématiques à la théorie des matrices de Dirac", *Annales de l'institut Henri Poincaré*, Volume 6 (1936) no. 2, p. 109-136) , that use a superscript plus sign $A^+$ for the same thing.  Page 119 of Pauli's paper has

> En général, nous désignerons par $\gamma^{+\mu}$ les matrices conjuguées hermitiques (transposées et conjuguées) des $\gamma^\mu$

and so on, with what I think is a typo in the next bit: "(c’est-à-dire telles que $\gamma^{+\mu}_{\rho\sigma}=\gamma^{*\mu}_{\rho\sigma}$)".

The leap from superscript $+$ to superscript $\dagger$ is understandable. It was taken, for instance,  by [Pauli](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.15.175) in his 1943 paper, "On Dirac's New Method of Field Quantization", if not earlier. (See equation (4) on p.176.)  But not, evidently, by Schwinger in his 1948 paper ["Quantum Electrodynamics. I. A Covariant Formulation"](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.74.1439), who uses $C^+$ for the Hermitian conjugate of $C$, on p.1441.

Comment: This paper https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1938.0058 (written in 1937) uses the notation on p.261.  So probably Furry did not introduce it in his 1938 paper.